# js и select в мобильной версии

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-development

Есть select и при onclick срабатывает функция:

```
function show_race()
    {
        var race = document.getElementById('raceSel').value;
        var img2 = document.getElementById("showRace");
        if (race == "Человек")
            img2.style.background = "url(../images/skins/human.png)";
        /*тут ещё пару if`ов.*/
    }
```

На комп. версии всё работает, но на телефонной if срабатывает не после выбора option, а сразу после нажатия, как это исправить и почему есть разница что код работает по-разному?

Comment: Тоесть функция сразу подбирает if в моб. версии, а в комп уже после выбора option проверяет

Comment: У select имеется элемент с атрибутом selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно вешать обработчик не на событие `onclick` (кликнули по элементу), а на событие `onchange` (изменили значение инпута)

Comment: ну да... Логично. Спасибо за ответ, заработало)

Comment: @BODN4R Если мой ответ решил Вашу проблему, то отметьте его как верный (галка под голосами)